# Url amigável em ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Gostaria de saber como fazer URL amigável em C# ASP.NET.

Tentei usar no arquivo: `global.asax` mas não funcionou.

Comment: É para uma aplicação nova ou ja existe? É baseado em Web Forms ou MVC?

Comment: @Intruso obrigado por responder, a aplicação já existe e é baseada em Web Forms

Answer (score 4):

De fato, não é pelo `Global.asax` apenas que se faz isso. [É preciso instalar este pacote primeiro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls/).

Instalado isso, você precisa colocar a linha abaixo no seu `Application_Start`:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Deve ser criado um arquivo chamado `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`. Dentro dele, deve haver um método em que a seguinte linha deve existir:

```
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
```

Assim sendo, se você tem um arquivo chamado `Teste.aspx` na raiz, com esta configuração, `Teste.aspx` será chamado como `/Teste`.

Mais informações? [Veja aqui](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx).

Comment: @Furlan, se precisar, dentro do `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` você pode registrar outras rotas usando o `routes.MapPageRoute`, a MSDN tem vários exemplos a respeito: [How to: Define Routes for Web Forms Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx)